# Why is my value being evaluated as undefined in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm encountering an issue while refactoring my navbar in Vue.js. Originally, I had it running outside my app.component, but now, after compressing and organizing it within my app.component along with the corresponding method and value assignment, the 'theme' value is being recognized as undefined.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue Basics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
</head>
<body>

<navbar
    :pages="pages"
    :active-page="activePage">
</navbar>


<page-viewer
        :page="pages[activePage]"
></page-viewer>


<script>
    let app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                activePage: 0,
                pages: [
                    {
                        link: {text: 'Home', url: 'index.html'},
                        pageTitle: 'Home',
                        content: 'This is the Home Content'
                    },
                    {
                        link: {text: 'About', url: 'about.html'},
                        pageTitle: 'About',
                        content: 'This is the About Content'
                    },
                    {
                        link: {text: 'Contact', url: 'contact.html'},
                        pageTitle: 'Contact',
                        content: 'This is the Contact Content'
                    }
                ]
            };
        }

    });

    app.component('page-viewer', {
        props: ['page'],
        template:
            `
            <div className="container">
                <h1>{{page.pageTitle}}</h1>
                <p>{{page.content}}</p>
            </div>
            `

    });

    app.component('navbar', {
        props: ['pages', 'activePage'],
        data() {
            return {
                theme: 'light'
            }
        },

        methods: {
            changeTheme() {
                let theme = 'light';
                if (this.theme == 'light')
                {
                    theme = 'dark';
                }
                this.theme = theme;
            }
        },
        template:
        `
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"
               :class="[\`navbar-${theme}\`,\`bg-${theme}\`, 'navbar', 'navbar-expand-lg']">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Vue</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li v-for="(page, index) in pages" class="nav-item" :key="index">
                <a :href="page.link.url"
                   :title="\`This link goes to the ${page.link.text} page\`"
                   @click.prevent="activePage = index"
                   aria-current="page"
                   class="nav-link"
                   :class="{active: activePage == index}"

                >{{ page.link.text }}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <form class="d-flex">
              <button class="btn btn-primary"
                      @click.prevent="changeTheme()">
                Toggle Button
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>

          </nav>
        `

    })

        app.mount('body')
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't interpolate ${theme} into template string, should be `['navbar-' + theme, ...`

Comment: or, try `\${theme}` - so the result will use the value of `theme` at "run-time" rather than immediately as it is doing now - escaping the back-ticks doesn't change how `${theme}` is interpreted inside those escaped back-ticks

Comment: Yeah..the forgotten \ before the ${theme} was the mistake..I'm so stupid. Thanks!